# Update Database Using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem updating my database, it is working fine using the general DB:: method but I think it would be better to use Eloquent.

The general DB method I used (which worked):

```
\DB::table('subscriptions')->update(array('state' => 'active'));
```

The Eloquent method I used (and it doesn't work):

```
    $user = $request->user();
    $user-> subscription-> state = 'active';
    $user-> save();
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Did you created model for your table `subscriptions`

Comment: Did you really have those spaces after the arrow notation? It should be `$user->save();` not `$user-> save();`

Comment: I tried without space too but it still doesn't work.

Comment: If the relationship `subscriptions` exists, you can do `$user->subscription->save()` instead.

Comment: @Omi yes I have protected `$table = 'subscriptions';`, protected `$fillable = ['user_id', 'product_id', 'product_name', 'state', 'activated_at', 'trial_ended_at', 'canceled_at'];`

Comment: @aynber Thank you so much! I think it works!

Comment: As aynber stated, you're trying to save the user, the user data is unmodified, you should save the subscription data, so: `$user->subscription->save()` instead of `$user->save()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\DB::table('subscriptions')->update(array('state' => 'active'));
```

When you do that you're updating the state of every row. Assuming you have proper relationship setup, you do one of the below.

```
$subscription = $request->user()->subscription;
$subscription->state = 'active';
$subscription->save();

$request->user()->subscription()->update(array('state' => 'active'));
```